# is it possible to get checkin differences using WIQL?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

This is in Team Explorer 2010

Question:
Using WIQL, is it possible to get the list of file differences due to checkins

1. for a given date range
2. for a given folder

Answer (score 0):

WIQL is about work items alone - so it isn't possible to retrieve this kind of information through this path.

Using the TFS data warehouse should provide with a viable alternative. A very nice introductory presentation can be found [here](http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/getting_started.html).

You should probably make a focus on the filters "Version Control Changeset" in combination with "Date" filter for your (1) & "Version Control File" for your (2).